# Delete y update no funcionan en apijson error MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, postman

Estoy desarrollando un api json. Me estoy encontrando que me salta el siguiente error:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

He ejecutado el `php artisan route:list` y las rutas están bien definidas. El problema que encuentro que el `update`y el `delete` no funcionan correctamente.

El route esta definido como en `web.php` :

```
Route::resource("perros","PerrosController");
```

Las peticiones con postman , las estoy enviando con el `id` en el caso del `delete` y con datos y id en el caso del `update`.

Tengo comentado el `csrfTocken`:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        //\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

Comment: ¿estás enviando un post o un delete en el caso del delete?

Comment: En caso de update , mando por `PUT` o `PATCH` y destroy por medio de `DELETE`

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo en cuenta que los navegadores normalmente no pueden enviar PUT, PATCH ni DELETE, Laravel espera entonces siempre que le envíen POST con un campo _method en el cual contenga el verbo deseado (PUT, PATCH, DELETE).

Si fuera un formulario, sería algo así:

```
<input type="hidden" value="DELETE" name="_method"  />
```

Comment: No me está ayudando pero se agradece

Answer (score -1):

La solución era tan fácil que era complicada

Yo estoy realizando una api json , donde postman siempre me manda un MethodNotAllowedHttpException`.

Por consiguiente no me funcionaba :

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
```

Que está bien para el caso de estar realizando un formulario en html.

### Primero : Definir correctamente el route

Hay que definir de forma correcta en `routes/api.php` las rutas correctas :

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/
Route::resource('perros', 'PerrosController');
```

### Segundo : Hacer las consultas correctas

#### En caso de UPDATE

```
PUT /api/perros/28?nombre=juanmaria HTTP/1.1
Host: apijson.local
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 81a331e8-2b9a-4b85-8c70-4000800dae9c
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Estaba escribiendo :

```
http://apijson.local/api/perros?id=28&nombre=juanmaria
```

Donde tiene que ser

```
http://apijson.local/api/clientes/28?nombre=juanmaria
```

#### En caso de DELETE

```
DELETE /api/clientes/28 HTTP/1.1
Host: apijson.local
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: f9b70db9-a50b-48c6-adea-9069ca4903f0
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Estaba escribiendo

```
http://apijson.local/api/clientes?id=28
```

Y tenia que escribir

```
http://apijson.local/api/clientes/28
```